# What about calls you can do safely in constructor?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, solc

As a matter of fact, there is more than one discussion about what are the call you can safely do in the constructor.

Someone thinks “avoid all external call”, some other says “avoid to use ‘this’ or address(this)” in the constructor, other are concerned about using ‘this’ after a ‘new’, other want to introduce warning and errors for the ‘this’ use and so on.

On GitHub/Ethereum do exist pages and pages about this, but true conclusions lack.

What is the recommended practice in Solidity? Does exist any list/cheat sheet about that?

EDIT: added some examples of such discussions as per smarx suggestion

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/583

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3875

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3843

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3861

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/1646#issuecomment-305026348

Comment: It would help if you would link to where you read those things.

Comment: You are right, I’ll do ASAP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a Solidity `constructor`:

- `this` is the address of the contract that is being constructed. (even after using `new` or calling an external function of another contract)
- `msg.sender` is the address of whoever or whatever is deploying the contract. (user account or another contract using `new`)
- You cannot call external functions on a contract that is being constructed (e.g. `this.foo();` inside the constructor function will revert the contract creation transaction)
- You can call internal functions of the contract that is being constructed. Inside that internal function, `this` and `msg.sender` will have the same values they did in the `constructor`.

In a `constructor`, you can safely deploy new contracts or call external functions on other contracts that have already been constructed.

Some of the confusion in the discussions you linked is based on `this.foo();` in the constructor function silently failing. This is no longer the case.

Comment: Thank you. This kind of operative answer is very useful here. May be we can add something about the needing to use () on modifiers without arguments used in constructor? Is it still needed?

Comment: @RickPark You don't need to add `()` to a modifier with 0 arguments when using it on the `constructor` or on a `function`. However, you can if you want to. It's optional now

Comment: I refer to this: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3853

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3824

Comment: @RickPark Yes, the `()` for a base constructor call without arguments is also optional, just like modifiers. The base constructor will be executed the same way in both cases, with or without the `()`

Comment: The discussion were because, on the contrary, the syntax error comes out when the () were not used in modifiers without arguments when applied to constructor. Of course, if the syntax error do not pop out, the code cannot be different...